# Are numpy-matrix-functions buffered?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

Are numpy matrix specific functions, such as `x.max()` buffered when applied several times?

So should one write:

```
bincount=np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x, minlength=data.max()+1), axis=0, arr=data)
```

or better

```
data_max=data.max()+1
bincount=np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x, minlength=data_max), axis=0, arr=data)
```

where data is e.g.

```
data=np.array([[1,2,5,4,8,7,8,9,14,8,14,5,2,1],
               [5,8,7,13,7,8,9,21,5,7,9,24,3,2]])
```

or of course even much larger

Comment: In general I'd advise running a benchmark and seeing the difference yourself if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating the question, it seems that you are asking whether numpy implements some form of *caching* of its results. While there is no general response to this question, for a method like `ndarray.max`, it is clear that no caching is done.

How can we know that without looking at the implementation? Consider that a caching scheme must resolve two problems:

- find a place to store the cached result(s);
- have a strategy to invalidate the cache once it no longer applies.

Although the first issue is non-trivial, the second one is the real killer. Not only can a numpy array be changed at any time, but the contents of the array can be shared by many objects. Additionally, C code can obtain the address of the internal buffers, and implement its own modifications to the underlying memory. Caching results would effectively disable many interesting uses of numpy.

You can consider numpy as a low-level library that doesn't concern itself with optimizations of that nature. If caching is needed, it should be implemented at a higher level, such as shown in your second example.

Comment: I got your point and I will clearify my question. My question only makes sense, when one does it again and again and data.max() does not change.

Comment: @benni Ok, you're actually talking about *caching* or *memoization*. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that numpy can be accessed by C code. That was new to me.

Comment: `ipython` `timeit` sometimes warns of buffering when run times differ widely.  But I think that buffering has more to do with reusing allocated memory buffers, than with reusing calculated values.

Answer (score 0):

Like Slater Tyranus pointed out, only a benchmakr will show any results:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def func_a(data):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x, minlength=data.max()+1), axis=0, arr=data)

def func_b(data):
    data_max=data.max()+1
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x, minlength=data_max), axis=0, arr=data)

setup = '''import numpy as np
data=np.array([[1,2,5,4,8,7,8,9,14,8,14,5,2,1],
               [5,8,7,13,7,8,9,21,5,7,9,24,3,2]])
from __main__ import func_a, func_b'''
```

> `min(timeit.Timer('func_a(data)', setup=setup).repeat(100,100))`
>
> 0.02922797203063965
>
> `min(timeit.Timer('func_b(data)', setup=setup).repeat(100,100))`
>
> 0.018524169921875

I tested also with much larger data. Overall one can say, it pays back calculating `data_max=data.max()` before. With much bigger arrays the discrepancy gets even larger.